# Toolbar and admob banner are covering the app content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a bpm app I am working on but I can get the layout to work right I have tried linear and relative layouts and I cant seem to make it work.

M top toolbar doesnt fill the full width of the screen and seems to have some sort of padding around it and it also covers the content in the app instead of the content starting after the toolbar.

The admob banner ad at the bottom seems to have the same problem. I couldn't get it to show up for a long time but i finally got it to show up except now it is covering the content of the app on the screen?

is there any way to make the toolbar line right up to the top with no padding around it and take up the full width of the screen... and also not cover the content.. the content would start after the toolbar...

and is there anyway to make it so the bottom banner ad isnt covering the app content as well???

[image: my app now]

here is my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/appView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/transitioning_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TempoActivity">

<!-- TOOLBAR START -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorRemoveAds"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<!-- TOOLBAR END -->

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/transitioning_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TempoActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/bpm"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bpmTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/initial_bpm_value"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="70sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tapButtonView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="@string/tap"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="90sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:text="@string/reset_instructions"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor" />

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/adView2">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

this is beyond confusing to me and i have been reading for hours any help would be appreciated

UPDATE*:
I HAVE MANAGED TO GET THE TOOLBAR PART WORKING USING LINEAR LAYOUTS!
but the admob banner has now disappeared off the page....

here is the layout i am working with now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<!-- TOOLBAR START -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorRemoveAds"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/ColorRemoveAds"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<!-- TOOLBAR END -->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/appView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/transitioning_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TempoActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/bpm"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bpmTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/initial_bpm_value"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="70sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tapButtonView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="@string/tap"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="90sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:text="@string/reset_instructions"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- PAGE BOTTOM ADMOB BANNER VIEW START -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/banneradview"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/bannerborderline"
    android:layout_below="@id/appView">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- PAGE BOTTOM ADMOB BANNER VIEW END -->
```

here is what the app looks like now 
[image: my app now]

Comment: Obviously you should position appView2 below toolbar and above AdView... Should be easy as you already using RelativeLayout as they parent. Where is the problem?

Comment: it is below toolbar and above adview?
so why is it not working

Comment: No, it doesn't.. RelativeLayout acts as FrameLayout if you don't set relationship... Also you have 2 appView2

Comment: i got the toolbar to work but not the admob banner... i edited my question with the updates

Comment: banners gone now tho

Comment: Flying spaghetti monster save us! Move banner before appView2 in XML but set appView2 to be above it via attribute. So order in XML should be Toolbar(parent top), AdView(parent bottom), appView2(below toolbar, above AdView), remove linearlayout and second appView2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/ColorRemoveAds"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/ColorRemoveAds"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/appView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transitioning_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".TempoActivity">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/bpm"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bpmTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/initial_bpm_value"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="70sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tapButtonView"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="@string/tap"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="90sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:text="@string/reset_instructions"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banneradview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/bannerborderline"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main change in `RelativeLayout`. It should be:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

in order to fill all `free` space, but not `all` space at all.

Comment: perfect this makes so much more sense to me thank you i knew i was doing WAYYY to much work this is perfect thanks alot